# TypeIt JQuery Plugin: Remove cursor when typing has completed

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using [typeit.jquery.js](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Customizable-Terminal-Text-Effect-TypeIt/) plugin, when a list of paragraphs start showing one after the other. Everything works fine, just one thing I couldn't manage: when typing on specific row has completed, remove `cursor`.

Plugin has an `attribute` `cursor: false`, but it takes away `cursor` from the beginning. I used same attribute in the function `callback: function(){}`, a function that executes after typing has completed, but it doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be appreciated!

```js
  $('.typeit-box3').typeIt({
    strings: 'First Paaragraph',
    typeSpeed: 100,
    autoStart: true,
    callback: function() {
    $('.typeit-box4').typeIt({
        strings: 'Second paragraph',
        typeSpeed: 100,
        autoStart: true,
        callback: function(){
          $('.typeit-box5').typeIt({
              strings: 'Third Paragraph',
              typeSpeed: 100,
              autoStart: true

              })
    }
    
    });
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeit/4.2.3/typeit.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li class="list" focus-next>
              <div class="typeit-box3"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="list" focus-next>
              <div  class="typeit-box4"></div>
            </li>
            <li class="list" focus-next>
 
              <div  class="typeit-box5" contenteditable></div>
             
            </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teuta --

Happy to help with this. The cursor of each instance of TypeIt has a 'ti-cursor' class, so, to hide each cursor after typing, you just need to target the class of each instance, and throw an additional class on there that has the display set to none.

Because the cursor has inline styles, you'll need to add "[style]" to your selector and use an !important flag.

See my example here. Notice the lines like this:

`$('.typeit-box3').find('.ti-cursor').addClass('is-hidden');`

Sorry for the difficulties -- I hope this helps!

```js
$('.typeit-box3').typeIt({
  strings: 'First Paaragraph',
  typeSpeed: 100,
  autoStart: true,
  callback: function() {
  
    $('.typeit-box3').find('.ti-cursor').addClass('is-hidden');
    $('.typeit-box4').typeIt({
      strings: 'Second paragraph',
      typeSpeed: 100,
      autoStart: true,
      callback: function() {
      
       $('.typeit-box4').find('.ti-cursor').addClass('is-hidden');
        $('.typeit-box5').typeIt({
          strings: 'Third Paragraph',
          typeSpeed: 100,
          autoStart: true

        })
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```css
.is-hidden[style] {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeit/4.2.3/typeit.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="list" focus-next>
    <div class="typeit-box3"></div>
  </li>
  <li class="list" focus-next>
    <div class="typeit-box4"></div>
  </li>
  <li class="list" focus-next>
    <div class="typeit-box5" contenteditable></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```js
$(function () {
  new TypeIt("#section01", {
    speed: 45,
    cursor: false,
  })
    .type("Hello.")
    .pause(500)
});
```

you can add an attribute:`cursor:false` to remove the cursor. the js links cited is below:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeit/5.0.2/typeit.min.js"></script>
```

For more information ,you can read the typeit's old version documentation:
https://www.typeitjs.com/docs/v7